# Spring reactive web client REST request with oauth token in case of 401 response

Tags: spring-webflux

I wanted to play around with Spring reactive web client and an actually simple example: Ask for a REST resource and in case of a 401 response get new OAuth access token.

The first part seemed to be easy:

```
return webClientBuilder
            .baseUrl(targetInstance.getBaseUrl())
            .build()
            .get().uri(targetInstance.getItemEndpointUrl())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ItemResponse.class)
            ....
```

But here the confusion already started. I tried something like

```
.onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, (response) -> {
            if(response.rawStatusCode() == 401) {
                   oAuthClient.initToken()
```

My token should then be saved within an instance JPA entity. But I have a lack of conceptual understanding here I guess. When the OAuth client receives the OAuth response I need to extract it first to persist it (as embedded object) within my instance entity. And therefore I need to block it, right?

```
.exchangeToMono(response -> {
    if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
        OAuthResponse oauthResponse = response.bodyToMono(OAuthResponse.class).block();
    }
```

Based on the response result of the OAuth client I need some kind of Mono to tell the actual REST client then if it should start a retry? And which way should be the preferred on: .retrieve() or .exchangeToMono()? So I'm a bit lost here if I'm on the right path or if something like that should better be done with the classic RestTemplate? But I've also read that the RestTemplate is no deprecated...

Thanks for sharing some thoughts with me.

Comment: you don't need to block on `bodyToMono`. You can `flatMap` on it to get the value out and then invoke your reactive db layer to persist it. This db layer show also return a Mono/Flux

Comment: Thanks for leaving a comment. Ok, because when I blocked I got an excpetion. And I saw there seems to be also a non-blocking PSQL driver. But I'm still unsure about the syntax. What's the best why to check for the 401 response. The "onStatus" or is "exchangeToMono" the way to prefere?

Comment: usually you would use `exchangeToMono` if you required access to additional parts of the response on top of just the status code. If you just need to check the status code then `retrieve` with `onStatus` will achieve your desired behaviour. Though at the end of the day they are both viable solutions and it is up to you to decide which you prefer to use.

Comment: ok. I've decided for the exchangeToMono. Here I can quite simply return an error of the result. But now I'm not sure how to proceed on here. Let's say I receive an error, how can I then go ahead with the `.retryWhen`?
`.map(result -> ResponseEntity.ok(result))
 .retryWhen(Retry.max(1)
  .doBeforeRetry(retry -> {
   oAuthtClient.initAccessToken()`
Let's say the OAuth client then returns simply a Mono<Boolean> whether auth was successful or not. How can one couple this with the retry to make sure the retry waits for this result to proceed with the next attempt? 
    .

Comment: What work is this: `.retryWhen(Retry.max(1)
     .filter(e -> {
      return oAuhtClient.initAccessToken().block();
     })`
But here I'm blocking which I actually do not want.

Comment: have you tried to use the `filterWhen` operator instead of `filter`. The response type is a `Publisher<Boolean>` instead of just a boolean allowing you to return a `Mono<Boolean>` and not requiring you to call `block()`

Comment: `filterWhen` for the apiClient response? Because my plan was to request the apiClient for an entiy and when the client receives a 401 it throws a `return Mono.error(new UnauthorizedException());` which can be then catched by the `Retry.filter(e -> e instance of UnauthorizedException..)`. But the `filterWhen` I would apply to the apiResponse and the client then would have to return some kind of emtpy fakedata to tell the calling instance that response is a 401, which does look a bit hacky to me. Maybe it cannot be solved without blocking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the meantime I've found a non-blocking way. Maybe not the best, but it works out well for me.

The client:

```
class ApiClient {

public Mono<MyResponse> getResponse(Tenant tenant) {
        return webClientBuilder
            .baseUrl(tenant.getUrl())
            .clientConnector(getClientConnector())
            .build()
            .get().uri("/api/my-content-entpoint")
            .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                    if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                        return response.bodyToMono(MyResponse.class);
                    } else if(response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)) {
                        return Mono.error(new MyOAuthExcpetion());
                    } else {
                        return Mono.empty();
                    }
                });
}

}
```

the service:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private final ApiClient apiClient;
    private final RetryStrategy retryStrategy;
    private final TenantService tenantService;

    public Mono<MyResponse> getResponse(String tenantId){
        return tenantService.getTenant(tenantId)
                .flatMap(tenant-> apiClient.getResponse(instance))
                .retryWhen(Retry.from(signals -> signals
                     .flatMap(retrySignal -> retryStrategy.reconnect(retrySignal, tenantId))));
    }
}
```

and the retry strategy

```
@Component
public class RetryStrategy {

   private final TenantService tenantService;

   public Publisher<? extends Long> reconnect(RetrySignal retrySignal, String tenantId) {
    
        long count = retrySignal.totalRetriesInARow();
        Throwable failure = retrySignal.failure();
        
        if(count > 0) {
            return Mono.error(new UnsupportedOperationException("Retry failed", failure));
        }
        
        Mono<Tenant> updatedTenant = null;
        
        if(failure instanceof MyOAuthExcpetion) {
            updatedTenant = tenantService.getTenant(tenantId)
                    .flatMap(tenant -> tenantService.refreshOAuth(tenant));
        }

        if(updatedTenant == null) {
            return Mono.error(new UnsupportedOperationException("Retry failed", failure));
        }
        
        return updatedTenant.then(Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(1))); 
    }
}
```

Happy for any feedback or improvements.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I went with prechecking the token before requests are being made:

```
client.get()
         .uri("...")
         .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + authenticator.getToken(client,token))
          .retrieve()
          ...
```

And in Authenticator Service I verify the validity of the token as follow:

```
String getToken(WebClient client, String token) {
    if (token == null || isTokenExpired(token)) {
               return this.fetchToken(client); // fetches a new token
            }
            return token;
        }
    
private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
            DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
            return jwt.getExpiresAt().before(new Date());
        }
```